# How can I make a folder expire and not serve up its contents after period of time? Using Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a hosted Apache based website. Currently, we create a new project folder on the site, and dump the flash based course up for review. Is there a way to make the content folder expire after a certain amount of time so that the content is no longer view-able?

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, using `mod_rewrite` module.

For example, to deny all requests since November 2014 you could use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} =2014
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} >10
RewriteRule .* /deny.html

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} >2014
RewriteRule .* /deny.html
```

To see all the available environment variables check the link below.

PS: you obviously need to provide some nice `/deny.html` page so that it was obvious for visitor what happened.

Or if you just need a standard 404/403 use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

References:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html